# Optimizing JOINED results with Order By clause

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

Consider following schema (available on [sqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/38fd79/4))

```
create table ad (
  id int primary key auto_increment,
  category_id int,
  city_id int,
  name varchar(255),
  key(category_id),
  key(city_id)
);

create table category (
  id int primary key auto_increment,
  name varchar(255)
);

create table city (
  id int primary key auto_increment,
  name varchar(255)
);

insert into category values (null, 'Category 1');
insert into category values (null, 'Category 2');
insert into category values (null, 'Category 3');

insert into city values (null, 'City 1');
insert into city values (null, 'City 2');

insert into ad values (null, 1, 1, "Category 1 city 1");
insert into ad values (null, 1, 2, "Category 1 city 2");
insert into ad values (null, 2, 1, "Category 2 city 1");
insert into ad values (null, 2, 2, "Category 2 city 2");
insert into ad values (null, 3, 1, "Category 3 city 1");
insert into ad values (null, 3, 2, "Category 3 city 2");
```

When executing simple joined query without any order by:

```
SELECT ad.id, ad.name, category.name, city.name FROM ad
INNER JOIN category ON category.id = ad.category_id
INNER JOIN city ON city.id = ad.city_id
```

the result is quite efficient:

[image]

However as soon as I add the ORDER BY clause, temporary table and file sort is involved:

```
SELECT ad.id, ad.name, category.name, city.name FROM ad
INNER JOIN category ON category.id = ad.category_id
INNER JOIN city ON city.id = ad.city_id
ORDER BY ad.id
```

[image]

**How to optimize such query?**

Comment: if you need sort  you need  a temporary  table for build the value to sort and then sort the resulting value ... where is the question ??????

Comment: Thank you for your helpful input.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I managed to find a solution by myself. First of all, one needs to efficiently calculate required ID's from the main table (having them filtered and sorted), then simply again join the results against that keys inside inner query:

```
SELECT ad.id, ad.name, category.name, city.name FROM
    (
        SELECT id FROM ad WHERE price <= 3000 ORDER BY id DESC
    ) AS v
JOIN ad ON v.id = ad.id
JOIN category ON category.id = ad.category_id
JOIN city ON city.id = ad.city_id
```

There're of course more columns involved in my case. With such query (having 60k records in the main table) the execution speed has increased from 0.16s to 0.004s, as long as I order by an indexed column(s).

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use a STRAIGTH_JOIN.

```
SELECT STRAIGHT_JOIN ad.id, ad.name, category.name, city.name FROM ad
INNER JOIN category ON category.id = ad.category_id
INNER JOIN city ON city.id = ad.city_id
ORDER BY ad.id
```

The MySQL optimizer has choosen to acces the table in the wrong order (city, ad, category) the optimal acces order would be (ad, category, city) the STRAIGTH_JOIN would force that acces table order.

Comment: 1 out of 3's not bad.

Comment: `STRAIGHT_JOIN` works nicely today; tomorrow it may force an order that is less beneficial.

Answer (score 0):

Premature panic.  With so few rows, `EXPLAIN` won't "prove" that the query plan is not good.  With a thousand ads and dozens of cities and categories, the Optimizer may pick `ad` as the first table to work with.

Also, the optimizer does not know whether your tables are 1 ad -to- many categories and cities.  Or many:many.

You have complained because you know that each `ad` is in only one category and one city?

"BNL" and "using join buffer" are quite efficient ways to perform queries -- They load everything, then manipulate it in an efficient way in RAM.

Also, "Using temporary" and "Using filesort" are not nearly as bad as they sound.  This is *usually* done in RAM with an efficient in-memory "qsort".

Comment: I have that production table with thousands of ads and query did produce same results. I already managed to optimize this query and going to post my solution as an answer come tomorrow.

Comment: @mike, please share your solution so everyone could learn from it :)